# why can we declare static object of a class inside the same class?

Tags: c++

```
class A
{
   static const A a;
}
```

Why we can do this , while we cannot do this without the word static?

Comment: What do you think it would do?

Comment: I guess one could even do such a thing without the `static` keyword if A is a template class, assuming there's no endless recursion. Something like `template<int n> class A{A<n-1> a;};`, and with a specialisation for zero. But don't ask me _why_ one would want to do that, or if there is any sensible usage for that, even if it's possible...

Comment: @Damon: A<n-1> is of completely different type than A<n>. Your sample can be as well written like 'class A{B b;};' and surely it's possible in C++.

Answer (score 4):

A `static` member has just one value; it's essentially a global variable scoped to the class declaration.

A non-`static` member is a value that appears in each class instance.
It doesn't make sense for a class to directly contain itself, since that would consume an infinite amount of memory.

You may want a pointer.